# Where am I most vulnerable when running Mac OS 10.6.8 Snow Leopard?

Tags: network, attacks, firewalls, operating-systems, macos

I have a challenge at work, one of our computers is running Mac OS 10.6.8 Snow Leopard. We have legacy software that's required to run the business, and so we have to have it online and on our network. This is a huge pain because I can't install most pieces of current software that would benefit from a new OS.

Because the OS is so old, what are the attack vectors that make it vulnerable (browsers perhaps?), and how can I harden the security as much as possible without actually taking it off the internet?

Comment: Pretty soon Firefox 45 ESR will be obsolete. That is the last browser to get security updates on this OS. Does having to run an obsolete browser count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS 10.6.8 has LOT of known CVEs, to be not exhaustive, and to go beyond browsers vulnerabilities, you OS is for example vulnerable to:

Directory Service which allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code or cause a denial of service (daemon crash) via a crafted message (CVE-2013-0984),

Its also vulnerable to multiple stack-based buffer overflows in the phar_set_inode function in phar_internal.h in PHP before 5.4.40, 5.5.x before 5.5.24, and 5.6.x before 5.6.8 allow remote attackers to execute arbitrary code via a crafted length value in a (1) tar, (2) phar, or (3) ZIP archive (CVE-2015-3329)

As well as being vulnerable to Integer overflow in the Security Framework that allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code or cause a denial of service (memory corruption and application crash) via crafted input.

You can see a list of known vulnerabilities [here](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-49/product_id-156/version_id-111857/Apple-Mac-Os-X-10.6.8.html)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the nature of the application that needs to be made available remotely it might be prudent to see if a reverse proxy or security gateway could be put in front.

In the extreme you could write a shim application that sits in front of the server and checks for buffer overflow attacks, validates inputs, and restricts xss just to name a few of the most common forms of attacks on older systems.